SPFx ContextualMenu with submenu
I'm creating an SPFx Extension. I currently have three commands and I want to group them into a submenu, but I'm unsure of how to add them. Here is my code for reference (I removed logic from some commands to condense the code):
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseListViewCommandSet,
  Command,
  IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters,
  ListViewStateChangedEventArgs
} from '@microsoft/sp-listview-extensibility';
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { BaseDialog, IDialogConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';
import { IHttpClientOptions} from "@microsoft/sp-http-base";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import * as React from 'react';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { IContextualMenuProps, IContextualMenuItem } from '@fluentui/react/lib/ContextualMenu';



class MyDialog extends BaseDialog {
  private documentID: string;
  private context: any;

  constructor(documentID: string, context: any) {
    super();
    this.documentID = documentID;
    this.context = context;
  }

  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      // excluded logic
    `;

    const exitButton = this.domElement.querySelector('#exitButton');
    if (exitButton) {
      exitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.close();
      });
    }
  
    setTimeout(() => {
      const formElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
      if (formElement) {
        formElement.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
          console.log('Submit event handler called');
          event.preventDefault();
          await this.updateItemProperties();
        });
      } else {
        console.error('Form element not found');
      }
    }, 0); 
  }
  

  private async updateItemProperties(): Promise<void> {
    // excluded logic
  }

  public getConfig(): IDialogConfiguration {
    return {
      isBlocking: false
    };
  }

  protected onAfterClose(): void {
    super.onAfterClose();
    this.domElement.innerHTML = "";
  }
}

export interface IKnowledgeAssetCommandSetCommandSetProperties {
  sampleTextOne: string;
  sampleTextTwo: string;
}

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'KnowledgeAssetCommandSetCommandSet';

export default class KnowledgeAssetCommandSetCommandSet extends BaseListViewCommandSet<IKnowledgeAssetCommandSetCommandSetProperties> {

  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'Initialized KnowledgeAssetCommandSetCommandSet');

    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    const compareTwoCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');
    const compareThreeCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_3');
    compareOneCommand.visible = false;
    compareTwoCommand.visible = false;
    compareThreeCommand.visible = false;

    this.context.listView.listViewStateChangedEvent.add(this, this._onListViewStateChanged);

    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'COMMAND_1':
        let documentID = JSON.stringify(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('ID'));
        this.displayAssetDetailsDialogue(documentID);
        this.triggerAssetCopy(documentID);
        break;
      case 'COMMAND_2':
        console.log("command 2");
        break;
      case 'COMMAND_3':
        console.log("command 3");
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown command');
    }
  }

  private displayAssetDetailsDialogue(documentID: string): void {
    const dialog: MyDialog = new MyDialog(documentID, this.context);
    dialog.show();
  }

  private triggerAssetCopy(DocumentID?:string): void {
    // excluded logic
  }

  private _onListViewStateChanged = (args: ListViewStateChangedEventArgs): void => {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'List view state changed');

    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    if (compareOneCommand) {
      compareOneCommand.visible = this.context.listView.selectedRows?.length === 1;
    }
    const compareTwoCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');
    if (compareTwoCommand) {
      compareTwoCommand.visible = this.context.listView.selectedRows?.length === 1;
    }
    const compareThreeCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_3');
    if (compareThreeCommand) {
      compareThreeCommand.visible = this.context.listView.selectedRows?.length === 1;
    }

    this.raiseOnChange();
  }
}


Please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.

At it's current state, I don't think we can create submenu in SPFx ListViewCommandSet.
Looking into class/interface definition, don't see it allows Children/Submenu Commands. Please see the MS provided class/interface definitions below
BaseListViewCommandSet => ListViewCommandSetContext

ListViewCommandSetContext => ICommandSetExtensionManifest

export declare interface ICommandSetExtensionManifest extends IClientSideExtensionManifest {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc IClientSideExtensionManifest.extensionType}
     */
    extensionType: 'ListViewCommandSet';
    /**
     * A table of items defined by this command set. The object key is the Item ID.
     *
     * @remarks
     *
     * The Item ID is a unique identifier that event handlers use to recognize the command
     * The identifier must consist of upper-case letters, numbers, and underscores.
     * Example: "SHOW_INFO"
     */
    items: {
        [itemId: string]: ICommandDefinition;
    };
}


No Children Property in ICommandDefinition
export declare interface ICommandDefinition {
    /**
     * A short label to be displayed by the associated button, menu item, etc.
     * Example: "Show information"
     */
    title: ILocalizedString;
    /**
     * Type of the item.
     * Currently only "command" is allowed.
     */
    type: 'command';
    /**
     * Custom accessibility text for the browser's "aria-label" attribute.  If omitted, the title property
     * will be used by default.
     * Example: "Show information.  Press ENTER to select."
     */
    ariaLabel?: ILocalizedString;
    /**
     * An optional URL for an image to be displayed next to the command. The requirements for this image
     * are defined by the type of extension; some extension types may not display the image at all.
     *
     * @remarks
     * This value can be an absolute URL (e.g. "http://example.com/icons/my-icon.png") or
     * a relative file path (e.g. "./icons/my-icon.png"). In the latter case, the path will be resolved relative to
     * the folder containing the input manifest. The icon file will be copied to the deployment folder like an asset,
     * and the output manifest's iconImageUrl will be replaced with a URL relative to the URL used to load all other
     * assets (the loaderConfig.internalModuleBaseUrls property).
     */
    iconImageUrl?: string;
}




Would it still not be possible even if using reactDOM? Or is that not recommended? Also, I was trying to reference this link (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/contextualmenu#implementation) but maybe that doesn't apply to what I am doing.

With the current version of this package? I don't think so. We can render any reactDom component, like custom dialog to collect data from user, from command event onExecute(). But can't construct nested menu, which is handled in ..commandSet.manifest.json file.
